# How do I show a error message if no product is found?

Tags: javascript, html, json, search

I have a search.js file that reads a json file and retrieves information about some products, and then displays it in the page.
I am trying to show a error message if no product is found when searching, and this part is almost working.
If a search for a non-existent product, the error message appears correctly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO64C.png)

The problem is, if I search for a product that the name isn't similar to another one, the error still appears.. for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHyaf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFXZU.png)

**Json file structure is like this:**

```
[
    {
        "nome": "Carro",
        "apelido": "ft.car",
        "desc": "descrição",
        "img": "/img/carro.png",
        "link": "/pag/carro.html"
    }, 
    {
        "nome": "Carreta Bi-Trem",
        "apelido": "ft.big.truck",
        "desc": "descrição",
        "img": "/img/carreta.png",
        "link": "/pag/carreta.html"
    }
...
]
```

**HTML of the error div:**

```
        <div class="col-12 d-none" id="avisoDeErro">
          <div class="alert alert-danger p-5 rounded shadow">
            <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill"></i> <strong>Erro</strong>
            <hr>
            <div class="fs-1 ">
              Nenhum produto encontrado.
              <p class="fw-light">Acha que deveria ter algo aqui? Entre em contato com o suporte.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**search.js file:**

```
const produtosCardTemplate = document.querySelector("[data-produtos-template]");
const produtosCardContainer = document.querySelector("[data-produtos-cards-container]");
const searchInput = document.querySelector("[data-search]");

let produtos = [];

searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
    produtos.forEach(produto => {
        console.log(value)
        const isVisible = value.split(' ').every(word => produto.nome.toLowerCase().includes(word)) || value.split('.').every(word => produto.apelido.toLowerCase().includes(word))
        produto.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible) //hide = display: none !important; 
        console.log(isVisible)
        
        // Show a error message
        if (!isVisible){
            let avisoErro = document.getElementById("avisoDeErro")
            avisoErro.classList.remove('d-none')
        } else {
            let avisoErro = document.getElementById("avisoDeErro")
            avisoErro.classList.add('d-none');
        }
    })
})

fetch("/produtos.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        produtos = data.map(produto => {
            // console.log(produto)

            const card = produtosCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
            const nome = card.querySelector("[data-nome]")
            const desc = card.querySelector("[data-desc]")
            const img = card.querySelector("[data-img]")
            const imgLink = card.querySelector("[data-img-link]")
            const link = card.querySelector("[data-link]")
            
            nome.textContent = produto.nome
            desc.textContent = produto.desc
            img.setAttribute("src", produto.img)
            imgLink.setAttribute("href", produto.link) 
            link.setAttribute("href", produto.link)

            produtosCardContainer.append(card)

            return {nome: produto.nome, apelido: produto.apelido, element: card}
        });
    });
```

I know that the problem is in my way of showing the error message

```
        if (!isVisible){
            let avisoErro = document.getElementById("avisoDeErro")
            avisoErro.classList.remove('d-none')
        } else {
            let avisoErro = document.getElementById("avisoDeErro")
            avisoErro.classList.add('d-none');
        }
```

But i can't think of another way of doing this

Tried changing the way to see if no product matched, with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have added the logic to display the error message inside the forEach loop, and as the loop runs for each product, if any of the products from the list does not match the search value, then an error message will be displayed, and also the matched products will be displayed.

```
searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  let avisoErro = document.getElementById("avisoDeErro")
  const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()

  const matchedProducts = produtos.filter(produto => {
    if(value.split(' ').every(word => produto.nome.toLowerCase().includes(word)) || value.split('.').every(word => produto.apelido.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
      produto.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible) //hide = display: none !important;
      return true;  
    }
  })

  const isVisible = matchedProducts.length <= 0
  // Show an error message only when none of the product matched
  if (!isVisible){
    avisoErro.classList.remove('d-none')
  } else {
    avisoErro.classList.add('d-none');
  }
})
```

Comment: I see what you mean, unfortunately the code provided ins't working, even after i attempted to change it, but now I will try to use the logic you made, thanks!

Comment: You just need to check on the isVisible condition, which I might have assumed wrong on the basis of the d-none class, other than that the logic will just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic provided by Yash Maheshwari above, i was able to solve my problem with this:

```
searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
let algumProdutoCorresponde = false;

produtos.forEach(produto => {
    console.log(value)
    const isVisible = value.split(' ').every(word => produto.nome.toLowerCase().includes(word)) || value.split('.').every(word => produto.apelido.toLowerCase().includes(word))
    produto.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible)

    if (isVisible) {
        algumProdutoCorresponde = true;
    }
})
let avisoErro = document.getElementById("avisoDeErro");
avisoErro.classList.toggle('d-none', algumProdutoCorresponde);
```

})